# how to generate list of installed packages from a full system backup?

Tags: debian, package-management

If I had a running debian system, the following command could be issued to get list of installed packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections > packages.lst
```

But now I have only a full backup of root partition (complete system backup) of the working system and nothing more.  How can I generate list of installed packages from these files?

Comment: Only the root partition - not the complete system? Which directories are on this partition?

Comment: I meant "complete system backup", edited question accordingly.

Comment: Also take light of this as a way to diff out just the ones you've installed.  It will take a little tweeking, but you'll get the idea:  https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-see-installed-programs-in-ubuntu#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chroot into it, and run dpkg would be the easiest thing.  See https://superuser.com/a/417004/20798 for how to get a working `/proc`, `/sys`, and `/dev` inside the chroot.

Since you have a working debian system outside the backup, you could probably just use

```
dpkg --admindir=dir --get-selections
```

The `dir` defaults to `/var/lib/dpkg`, so put the path to your backup's `/var/lib/dpkg`.

---

Don't forget that `dpkg --get-selections` doesn't show which packages were manually installed, and which were only installed to satisfy dependencies (and thus should be auto-removed when no longer needed because newer versions of the packages you actually want have different deps, or because you purge a manually installed package.)

I use aptitude, which makes it easy to mark *everything* as auto-installed, then go through and mark some packages as manually installed until nothing you want to keep is getting auto-removed.  Start with big meta-packages, like `build-essential`, the Debian equivalents of `ubuntu-standard` and `ubuntu-desktop`, and stuff like that.  In aptitude, hit `r` to see the reverse-depends of a package (pkgs that depend on it).

Comment: You can use `apt-mark` or (far more convenient but not installed by default) `apt-clone` to clone a set of installed packages including the automatic/manual flag.

Comment: `dpkg --admindir=dir --get-selections` also lists deinstalled packages and other non-installed ones. You need to parse it to get only installed packages.

Comment: @terdon: I assume the intended usage was to feed the list to `dpkg --set-selections`.  In which case, run `aptitude` before letting dpkg actually act on those selections, and mark all the to-be-uninstalled packages as don't-change.  Or go through the list and see which cruft you actually want to purge (and change it from deinstall to purge).

Answer (score 4):

Peter's [approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230736/22222) is better but you could also just parse `/var/lib/dpkg/status` which doesn't require a `chroot`:

```
 $ perl -00ne 'if(/: install/){/Package:\s*(\S+)/ && print "$1\n"}' /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

On my machine, that returned the same list of packages as `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$NF=="install"{print $1}'` (the `awk` parsing is needed because otherwise it also shows deinstalled packages).

Comment: downvote, because it gives different set of packages on my running system. I have 4113 packages according to `dpkg --get-selections`, 3925 packages according to your one-liner and 1473 packages missing in your one-liner.

Comment: @ceremcem yes, as I said in my answer, that's because `dpkg --get-selections` doesn't list only installed packages. It will also show uninstalled ones. Compare the output of my one-liner to that of  `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$NF=="install"{print $1}'` instead. Alternatively, just run `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall` to see the various packages you don't want listed.

Comment: The `dpkg_installed` command returns 193 less packages than `dpkg --get-selections` commad. your one-liner has 1204 additional, 1473 missing packages when compared to `dpkg --get-selections` command and 1204 additional, 1280 missing packages when compared to `dpkg_installed` command.

Comment: @ceremcem what's `dpkg_installed`? Where can I get it, it sounds useful and I'd like to check this on my machine. I can tell you that here, `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$NF=="install"{print $1}'` and the perl one-liner return the same list. In any case, there's no point in comparing it to `dpkg --get-selections` since that prints various things you don't want.

Comment: Pardon me for fabricating something like a non-understandable joke, I used `dpkg_installed` in place of  `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$NF=="install"{print $1}'`. By the way, I run couple of tests and it seems that there something wrong with my current installation, since I can not find some of my installed applications in `dpkg --get-selections` list. I'm toggling my downvote till I run these commands on some other installations.

Comment: @ceremcem I don't really know the details either, but I've had confusing results with `dpkg --get-selections` as well. Presumably, I need to read the man page more carefully. As a workaround, I use `dpkg -l | grep ^ii` which should list only installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a listing using of you packages using :

`awk '/Package:/ {print $2}' /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: That will not only show installed packages.